# Unable to mock static invocations using JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I am having difficulty mocking static invocations. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

My stripped down source code:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

public class OptionsBusinessEventFormatter {

  void process() {
    System.out.println("Testing testing ");
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    System.out.println("request = " + request);
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("returnedURI"));
  }
}
```

My unit test

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class OptionsBusinessEventFormatterTest {

  private OptionsBusinessEventFormatter optionsBusinessEventFormatter;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
     this.optionsBusinessEventFormatter = new OptionsBusinessEventFormatter();
  }

  @Test
  public void process_HappyPath() {
      final MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
      request.setParameters(map);
      new Expectations() {
          @Mocked ServletActionContext servletContext;
          {
              ServletActionContext.getRequest();
              result = request;
          }
      };
      this.optionsBusinessEventFormatter.process();
  }
}
```

I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Native library for Attach API not available in this JRE
    at mockit.internal.startup.AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(AgentLoader.java:88)
    at mockit.internal.startup.AgentLoader.loadAgent(AgentLoader.java:47)
    at mockit.internal.startup.AgentInitialization.loadAgentFromLocalJarFile(AgentInitialization.java:27)
    at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initializeIfPossible(Startup.java:252)
    at org.junit.runner.Runner.<clinit>(Runner.java:22)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no attach in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.<clinit>(WindowsVirtualMachine.java:185)
    at mockit.internal.startup.AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(AgentLoader.java:66)
    ... 16 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.junit.internal.runners.ErrorReportingRunner
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
```

I even tried using MockUp instance as given below

```
  public class MockServletActionContext extends MockUp<ServletActionContext> {

      private final MockHttpServletRequest request;

      public MockServletActionContext(MockHttpServletRequest request) {
          this.request = request;
      }

      @Mock void $init() {}

      @Mock
      public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
          return this.request;
      }
  }
```

I get the same error.

Comment: As the exception message says, the JRE on which the test was executed lacks the Attach API native library, which JMockit needs. Probably, you are using a plain JRE, which indeed does not contain `attach.dll`.  To fix this, configure your IDE to use the JRE from a full JDK installation (ie, `<jdkDir>\jre`).

Comment: I have installed the Oracle Java 7 JDK and have set the JAVA_HOME and appended the $JAVA_HOME/bin to existing $PATH variable.

Comment: Environment variables like JAVA_HOME, PATH, etc. are not used by JMockit. Probably not even your Java IDE (assuming one is being used) makes use of them. If tests are executed through an IDE, you need to configure it to use the desired JDK/JRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to the following things to get the execution to run from Eclipse

```
Debug > Create new Launch Config> Select a Test Case >  Arguments > VM Arguments > Path to jMockit Jar.
```

With Maven

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/com/googlecode/jmockit/jmockit/${jmockit.version}/jmockit-${jmockit.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This worked for me.